# htaccess multiple directory redirect

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, directory

I would like to know how you can filter out a multiple list of URL, and redirect to a page .

Example:

```
www.domain.de/notuse/seite1.html

www.domain.de/dir1/notuse/seite1.html

www.domain.de/dir1/dir2/notuse/seite1.html
```

I want now " **notuse** " have filtered and since I am total beginner , I'm not sure if that is correct :

```
RedirectMatch permanent ^.+notuse/ http://www.domain.de/new-directory/index.html
```

What would you suggest?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change your regex patterns :

```
RedirectMatch ^/.*notuse/site1\.html$ http://domain.de/new-dir/index.html
```

**.*** matches any charecters zero more times, so here it would match **/dir1/dir2** if present in Request_uri.